# Orchard : maintaining a list of custom content type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I am maintaining a list of 'Events' (custom content type) and the list can have only 1 upcoming event but several 'Events' whose date has been passed...

I want to apply a check that if the DATE is of future then show the details of that event on the 'Events page' and show the list of passed events in the widget.

where and How can i apply this filter based on date ?

Thanks in advance.
xtremist

Comment: not sure what widget is, or how you store your content... as question with many more questions am afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Projector. You can then make two queries with filters for future and past events and then display one result for future events and as many as you want for past ones.